# Itemize and alignment of text

Tags: spacing

I would like to look my text like this:

```
\item Parameter     and the text should continue at the same "tab space"
\item Variable      so it looks like this
```

Can seem to find an easy way to do this.

Edit: sorry question is unclear.
It supposed to be an itemize and I want to align the text that describes the parameters and variables on the right like the example above.

Comment: Do you mean you want to format the _source file_ rather than the output? If so that is entirely a question about the editor you use to make the file, not about TeX but you have not said which editor that is.

Comment: Are the words *parameter* and *variable* part of a `description` environment instead of `itemize`?

Comment: see edit in post

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try this:

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{listliketab}
   \begin{document}

   \storestyleof{itemize}
   \begin{listliketab}
   \begin{tabular}{Llll}
   \textbullet &   Parameter & and the text should continue at the same "tab space"   \\
   \textbullet &  Variable & so it looks like this  \\
   \end{tabular}
   \end{listliketab}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\itemshape[1]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[#1]%
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 

  \begin{description}[align=right]
    \item[\itemshape{circle} First Item] Description of first item
    \item[\itemshape{circle} Second Item] Description of second item
    \item[\itemshape{circle} Third Item] Description of third item
    \item[\itemshape{circle} Fourth Item] Description of fourth item
  \end{description}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[but I am not sure, why the first bullet is not aligned]

Comment: Why did you use `beamer` class?